# How can I make my application running while it is close?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

How can I make my application running while it is close?
but it is active application.

how can I make my android app. updates its own in every minute while it is minimized?

Comment: You can use services for that, read it here more about services, http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Use a foreground service http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service. Service runs in background.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-service-tutorial.html